# return to the original view in view-based-Application

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uiview

In my app I show a view by this code

```
[self.view addSubview:view2];
```

now  i want to call the original view from a button (in view2).

thank you.

Comment: It's unusual for a view to message another view. Do you mean that you want a view to send a message to the view controller? Please tell us a little more clearly what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by removing the view2. i.e

```
[view2 removeFromSuperview];
```

An alternative is to use Navigation Controller or simply present Modal View

```
// present on top of the current view
[self presentModalViewController:viewController2 animated:YES];
```

on second view controller's button tap event

```
// remove and back to previous view
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```